# Storing a lambda function in the Google App Engine Datastore (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, lambda, google-cloud-datastore

I am creating a bunch of Foo objects in GAE.

I want each Foo to have a function called fooify().
Calling fooify(object) should return object, but transformed in some way.

For example, fooify([2,3]) might return:

- [1,2] (fooify = lambda x: [n-1 for n in x])
- [2,3] (fooify = lambda x: x)
- [2,4] (fooify = lambda x: [x[0],x[1]+1])

I want to be able to define what fooify does when I create my objects, preferably with something like:

```
foo1=Foo()
foo1.fooify=lambda x: [n^2 for n in x]
foo1.put()
```

The Foo class looks like:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    name=ndb.StringProperty(default="generic foo", indexed=True)
    fooify=ndb.SOMETHINGProperty(indexed=False)    # This contains the function
```

I know this isn't what the datastore is made for, but would still like to do it.
Currently the only option I can see is something like the following:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    name=ndb.StringProperty(default="generic foo", indexed=True)
    fooify_str=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)    # Contains something like "lambda x: [n+3 for n in x]"

    def fooify(self,obj):
        func = eval(self.fooify_str)
        return func(obj)
```

Which uses eval() to create the main part of the fooify function. I don't want to use eval() because it seems sort of hack-ish, and it also means that I have to write all the fooify_str functions as strings, (annoying - no syntax highlighting, etc.)

Is there another way around this that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't see many alternatives.  you can't pickle a lambda.  Where are these lambda defintions coming from.  If they are going to be in code somewhere then just store a name and look it up.  If it's coming from a webrequest / user input you would have to do something like eval to create it in the first place.

Comment: It's coming from the code originally, when I build lots of Foos (100s), but I also want to be able to make new Foos once it's running through some sort of admin interface. I guess eval may be the way to do this...

Answer (score 2):

Using [polymodel](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass) may suit your needs if your different `fooify` functions are somewhat organized in a class hierarchy.

You can define your model:

```
class Foo(polymodel.PolyModel):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()

class MyFirstFoo(Foo):
  def fooify(self, obj):
    ...

class MySecondFoo(Foo):
  def fooify(self, obj):
    ...
```

ndb will store these all under the `Foo` kind, so any query over `Foo` will return all the results (i.e. `Foo.query().filter(...)`. However, it keeps track of the class hierarchy, so when you load the entity it knows it is a `MyFirstFoo` versus `MySecondFoo`.